# AngularJS : Getting data from Factory and update Controller scope and view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller, angular-promise

Hello guys I really need help and advice on this factory and controller issue I am having.

1. I have a factory that gets data from the server

   ```
   sp.factory('homeFeed',['$window','$http','auth',function($window,$http,auth){
   var url = auth.url;
   var version = auth.version;
   var HomeFeed = {};

   HomeFeed.getFeeds = function(user){
       //setting variable for get request on home feed
       var req = {
           method: 'GET',
           url: url + version + '/Feed',
           headers: {
               'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
               'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
           },
       }

       return $http(req).success(function(res){
           return res;
       });
   };

   return HomeFeed;
   }]);
   ```
2. controller--

   ```
   sp.controller('HomeCtrl',['$scope','homeFeed','$window',function($scope,homeFeed,$window){
   //getting all the home feed data
   $scope.feeds = homeFeed.getFeeds(JSON.parse($window.localStorage['SP-User']))


   }]);
   ```

however, after the respond from the server, my view is not updated and the $scope.feeds is not updated as well.  Greatly appreciate your help

Comment: I think you should pass a callback to getFeeds, call it inside success and update your $scope.feeds there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are doing async `$http` call then that data would not be available at that instance of time. It would be available when ajax call succeeded. You need to use `.then` function which will create a promise chain and will execute a function when `.success` function returns a data.

**Controller**

```
sp.controller('HomeCtrl',['$scope','homeFeed','$window',
   function($scope,homeFeed,$window){
     //getting all the home feed data
     homeFeed.getFeeds(JSON.parse($window.localStorage['SP-User']))
     .then(function(data){
        $scope.feeds = data 
     });
   }
]);
```